# CSS positioning: how to make it relative to one element but not the other?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to do an inter-fading slideshow JS.

it works perfectly if all the images are in `position: absolute`, under the parent`div`.

Problem arises when there are images with different orientations and aspect ratios, they all stick to the upper-left corner of the parent `div` when I want them to align with the center (both horizontal and vertical) of the`div`.

If I change them to `position:relative`, they would appear next to the existing image while starting to fade in because the original hasn't faded out yet.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/chocobo/ERH54/9/

(all credit goes to the original author: Torsten Baldes)

EDIT: Horizontal-centering is made possible, how about vertical-centering?

Comment: Codes and examples are like _gold_ around here. When people see it, they want to help more :)

Comment: What JS framework are you using? Could you post an example on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking if I posted that.. it'd be a tl;dr for a lot of people.

Comment: @user1017942: You should always try to provide minimal examples anyway even if its only for your own debugging's sake. And skipping a long piece of code is less worse then not even having the code to ignore in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not suggesting this is the best way, but it works:

Start by wrapping your images in list item elements. Add the following class to your CSS:

```
.innerfade li { width: 100%; }
```

Next, wrap your images within div elements and style them with text-align: center. Hopefully you should see your images aligned horizontally down the middle.

```
<ul id="rotation" class="innerfade">
    <li><div style="text-align: center;"><img src="http://www.google.com/images/nav_logo95.png"></div></li>
    <li><div style="text-align: center;"><img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/images/ww/met/slimheader/yahoo-logo-sm-png8.png"></div></li>
    <li><div style="text-align: center;"><img src="http://l.yimg.com/cv/mntl/aut/11q3/img_9224c7f0.jpg"></div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks it works, however is vertical centering possible? Since vertical-align: middle doesn't work

Comment: For vertically centering elements, check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159542/vertically-center-html-element-with-css

Comment: Thanks for the constructive comments. I didn't try to work around this problem at last. I've chosen some jQuery plugins instead. That simplified the operation, and I just lived with the result.