# Vertically Center HTML Element Within a Div of Dynamic Height

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [vertical-align: middle doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967217/vertical-align-middle-doesnt-work)

How can i make sure that the `<a></a>` is vertically centered in this div, regardless of the size of the div:

http://jsfiddle.net/XF9WM/

Thanks

Comment: You are using rgba colors.  Is it then safe to assume you aren't targeting older browsers?

Answer (score 4):

Using `display:table` and `display:table-cell`, which works in all modern browsers (IE 8+):

```css
.post {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    display:table;
}

.post h2 {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.post h2 a {
    color: #f7f7f7;
    font-size: 2.2em;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: +1 Yes that's a good solution. As long as you don't have people using IE 7 or older I think. Here's a good article about it: http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to achieve it in a different way, (just for fun), and this one is working too:
[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XF9WM/93/)

The idea is using a `:before` block element of 50% height.

```css
html, body{
 height:100%;
}

.post {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.post h2:before{
   content:"";
   display:block;
   height:50%;
}

.post h2 {   
    text-align:center;   
    height:100%; 
}

.post h2 a {
    color: #f7f7f7;
    font-size: 2.2em;
    margin-top:-20px;
    display: block;
}
```

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: Not really any flexibility in resizing the font-size of `.post h2 a`.

Answer (score 1):

**[UPDATED]**

You can also do it like this: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XF9WM/59/)

```css
.post {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    position:relative;    
}

.post h2 {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;

}

.post h2 a {
    line-height:100%;
    color: #f7f7f7;
    font-size: 2.2em;
    margin-top:-20px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm this only seems to work for the 200px height case.

Comment: yes you are right...  now I fixed but in a different way :-)

Comment: Ooops,... ok, forget my post, there is a similar answer above

Answer (score 1):

Give your link a line-height larger than the text will ever be, and vertically align it in the middle.  Then absolutely position it's parent within the div to be at `top: 50%` and margin top minus half the link's line-height:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XF9WM/23/)

```css
.post {
    position: relative;
}
.post h2 {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -150px;
}
.post h2 a {
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 300px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

It even works in IE7.

Comment: +1 seems to work in all cases.

Comment: Doesn't really work "regardless of any size".

Comment: @wex - what size does it not work for?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind adding an extra HTML class, your simplest way is just to use vertical-align: middle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/HtNJM/

```
<div class="post">
    <span></span><h2><a href="#">Hello!</a></h2>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.post {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px; }

.post span {
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; }

.post h2 {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; }

.post h2 a {
    color: #f7f7f7;
    font-size: 2.2em;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
    display: block; }
```