# Vertically center content within a div of dynamic height

Tags: css, html, center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vertically Center HTML Element Within a Div of Dynamic Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159542/vertically-center-html-element-within-a-div-of-dynamic-height)

I am currently designing a website for which i need to vertically center some content. The design is pretty basic: a fixed height header (left-aligned and always at the top of the page), and underneath that vertically centered images in a horizontal row (yes, horizontal scrolling, i know).

Ideally i would want the vertical centering of the images to be based on the 100% height of the viewport - the header (so a dynamic height that prevents the content from overlapping the header).

An example of the website can be found on http://bit.ly/vl1XNY, which is currently using tables for layout. The css and html i used can be found there too (of course).

I am aware of various solutions for centering content vertically within a container of fixed height, however none of them have worked for me because i'm using variable height and do not want to use absolute positioning (to prevent overlap). I have looked around and tried the table-cell solution, the line-height one, and the absolute positioning one.

So far the only solution that has worked exactly as i intended was using tables. But i would like to refrain from using them. Is anyone aware of a valid css and html solution for this problem? Or at least a more graceful solution?

Comment: The table-cell solutions should have the same effect as using table elements. You could also try: http://www.student.oulu.fi/~laurirai/www/css/middle/#valhib

Comment: If the absolute positioning with 50% doesn't work... I'd personally use tables. It's not a whole website made of tables, it's tabular data (in a  way) so there's no crime about it. Your example uses tables...

Comment: @utopicam, yeah i think i will continue using tables, it seems to be the only solution for a layout like this. Btw. the example i linked to was the solution i'd come up with so far. And yeah it uses tables, as it was the only way to achieve the layout i wanted. It's a shame that it's not just the images that are in a table, but the whole page, but was the only way i could achieve the look i was after.

Comment: Yes, with an auto height it will not work, you would need to calculate current viewport height with javascript

Answer (score 16):

Wohh, talk about timing, i was looking for such a solution just a few minutes ago and stumbled upon an article on this subject exactly, you can read it all about it here: [Centering in the Unknown](http://css-tricks.com/14745-centering-in-the-unknown/).

You can easily modify your code to make it work like so:

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 blue;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#wrapper:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.center {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 460px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="center">
        <img src="images/a_1.jpg" alt=" ">
    </div>
    <div class="center">
        <img src="images/a_2.jpg" alt=" ">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok, looks good! but where do i add my header menu? I've tried it with just the photo's, and it works. But when i add the header in the #wrapper the whole page is pushed down, out of the viewport (thanks to the pseudo-element). do you know how to solve this? (example: http://bit.ly/vFqBw0)

Comment: Add your header above your #wrapper and that should fix it.

Comment: yeah but when i do that, the total height exceeds 100%, so there is a permanent scroll bar.. Any way around that? I haven't been able to find it without compromising the layout.. (see http://bit.ly/vFqBw0)

Comment: I'm on a small netbook right now so can't tell the difference but you can remove the `height:100%` declaration from your `#wrapper` and that should allow the overflow to flow naturally and should eliminate the scrollbar from where it is not needed. (large screens)

Comment: this is the coolest answer to this problem i've seen.  a lot of people say use `display:table-cell` but that requires extra markup, and messes with IE7 and8.  Thanks for this.

Comment: easy explanaation thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
<div style="display:table-cell;">
    <img src="..." style="... vertical-align:middle;">
    <img src="..." style="... vertical-align:middle;">
</div>
```

Please check the above code in the context of all HTML:

```
<style type="text/css">
    html, body {height:100%;}
        body {
        margin:0; padding:0;
    }
    #header {
        height:1.7em;
    }

    #content {
        display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; height:500px;
    }

</style>

<div id="header"></div>    
<div id="content">
    <img src="..." style="... vertical-align:middle;">
    <img src="..." style="... vertical-align:middle;">
</div>
```

This will only work with a fixed height table-cell, which can be achieved by calculating current viewport height with javascript

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've tried it, but for me it only works with a fixed height, when using a variable height (as in 100%), it doesn't work (example: http://bit.ly/vFqBw0). Any suggestions?

Comment: Have tried to expand upon your suggestion using http://bit.ly/6c3Ixl, but this didn't work as the header won't stretch the full 100% anymore. See http://bit.ly/uX9Nz1.